# Naming an ensemble of compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, identification

As part of intern work I am running simulations on a group of compounds, but as it is I have little in the way of O-Chem experience and I wanted to be able to at least get some direction on naming these compounds (maybe some examples).

I think I've got the names of the functional groups down right, and I've recognized a few of the reaction types, but after that what do I do?

What are the other 2 reaction types?

How should I take the names of the products/reactants and the functional group names and stick em together.

What about when the functional group listed is bigger than the main group. (example R8 and ring opening)?
[image]

I should have written F1-F8 but R1-R8 represent functional groups if I'm not mistakened.
Here are my best guesses

R1:alkane

R2:alkene

R3:alkyne

R4:amine

R5:alcohol

R6:ketone

R7:amide

R8:benzene

Answer (score 2):

Pericyclic ring opening, cyclobutene to butadiene (Woodward-Hoffmann rules). 
Claisen rearrangement, vinyl ether to ketone (re bullvalene). 
Diels-Alder addition. 
Sn2 displacement; AgF will move that along (not a soft Lewis base solvent). 
Alkene to expoxide is *not* done with water.  Direct catalytic oxidation, base elimination from the cyanohydrin (first adding HOX), peracids. 
Primary alcohol to aldehyde is Jones reagent (in water), Collins reagent (in anhydrous pyrdine, and much better. There is no product in the sludge), Swern oxidation (makes you unpopular downwind), fancier stuff. 
Markovnikov addition of HCl to an alkene.

The Woodward-Hoffmann rules tell you what conditions are required (thermal vs. photochemical) and the associated stereochemistry (suprafacial vs. antarafacial) re conservation of orbital symmetry.

Comment: Consider Foldit, the minimizing protein conformation energy game. The very best players are not chemists. The best drone drivers are gamers not pilots. I'm rooting for the OP discovering something useful.